# How to modify DLL toString method?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

How can i make doubly linked lists print in this order:
1<->2<->3<->4<->5<-> etc..
For example i have a code here that print in this order:
<-1-><-2-><-3-><-4-><-5->
What should i modify in my `toString();` function ?

```
  @Override
        public String toString() {
            String ret = new String();
            if (first != null) {
                DLLNode<E> tmp = first;
                ret += tmp + "<->";
                while (tmp.succ != null) {
                    tmp = tmp.succ;
                    ret += tmp;
                }
            } else
                ret = "Empty list";
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: *"i have a code here that print in this order:"*: but that isn't the code you have provided in the question...

Comment: Please provide a runnable example which illustrates your question.